# View.GONE занимает место

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

Я получаю данные с Firebase и при помощи RadioButton сортирую показываемые данные. Все, вроде работает, но всё равно остаётся пустое место, когда один из типов данных  скрывается. Подскажите в чем проблема.

**Так я пытаюсь скрывать данные:**

```
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, Person model,
                                  int position) {
    if (viewHolder instanceof PersonType1ViewHolder) {
        ((PersonType1ViewHolder) viewHolder).time.setText("Full time: " + model.getTime());
        if (activate) {
            viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return;
    }
    if (viewHolder instanceof PersonType2ViewHolder) {
        ((PersonType2ViewHolder) viewHolder).time.setText("Full time2: " + model.getTime());
        if (activate2) {
            viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Возможно проблема в разметке. Покажите разметку. Хотя... Вы скрываете `itemView`... Наверное там другие правила. Обычно так не делают и надо удалять просто элементы из списка, а не скрывать их в этом случае.

Answer (score 2):

Месторасположение элементов определяется в методе layout их родителя. Чтобы вьюшка с visability GONE не влияла на расположение других элементов - родительская вьюшка должна обрабатывать это в свое layout. Не удивлюсь, если recyclerView не обрабатывает GONE, вполне уместно не ожидать в нем невидимых элементов, как по мне.

Еще вариант - нужно вручную вызывать requestLayout для родителя itemView.

Как по мне верным путем будет изменение датасета и в не сокрытие вьюшек, а просто их полное отсутствие. Держите 2 списка в адаптере - полный и отфильтрованный. Первый хранится всегда, второй генерируется из первого по правилам фильтра и используется для отображения

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насколько это правильно, но я просто программно задал параметры

```
viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```